# How to get JSON data as a table with KeyPath using Function dbo.JSONHierarchy?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

**Background of the Case:**
I am using FUNCTION dbo.JSONHierarchy to view the data from any JSON data in a Tabular Format.

FUNCTION dbo.JSONHierarchy was created by Phil Factor and available in below links:

[Consuming hierarchical JSON documents in SQL Server using OpenJSON](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/consuming-hierarchical-json-documents-sql-server-using-openjson/)

For Example, I have sample JSON data as below:

```
DECLARE @JSONdata nvarchar(MAX) = 
'{
    "menu": {
        "id": "file",
        "value": "File",
        "popup": {
            "menuitem": [
                {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
                {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
                {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
            ],
            "backmenuitem": [
                {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
            ]
        }
    }
}';
```

Colourising the JSON for better understanding:
[image]
When i execute this function with JSON sample data:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.JSONHierarchy(@JSONData,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT)
```

The Output of the above Function dbo.JSONHierarchy is as below:
[image]

The Advantage of this Function is the **Element_Id** and **Parent_ID** which shows the Order of Elements and to which parent it belongs to as it was mentioned in **@JSONdata**

**My Requirement:**
Now, with this info in place, i wanted to include **KeyPath** and **JSONdata_Used** in the Resultset
[image]

**What was Done by Me:**
While i was trying to Add these additional fields, the resultset is not being extracted correctly for complex JSONdata.

I figured out that this Function is calling the same Function for deeper levels where the Resultset is not correct.

when I tried using Debugger, the Values with in the Variables are showing correct surprisingly. But, the Resultset is not as expected.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.JSONHierarchy
(
    @JSONData VARCHAR(MAX),
    @Parent_object_ID INT = NULL,
    @MaxObject_id INT = 0,
    @type INT = NULL
)
RETURNS @ReturnTable TABLE
(
    Element_ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY, /* internal surrogate primary key gives the order of parsing and the list order */
    SequenceNo INT NULL,                       /* the sequence number in a list */
    Parent_ID INT,                             /* if the element has a parent then it is in this column. The document is the ultimate parent, so you can get the structure from recursing from the document */
    Object_ID INT,                             /* each list or object has an object id. This ties all elements to a parent. Lists are treated as objects here */
    Name NVARCHAR(2000),                       /* the name of the object */
    LocationPath NVARCHAR(MAX),                /* Updated to hold the full location path */
    StringValue NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,        /*the string representation of the value of the element. */
    ValueType VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL             /* the declared type of the value represented as a string in StringValue*/
)
AS
BEGIN
    --the types of JSON
    DECLARE @null INT = 0,
            @string INT = 1,
            @int INT = 2,
            @boolean INT = 3,
            @array INT = 4,
            @object INT = 5;

    DECLARE @OpenJSONData TABLE
    (
        sequence INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
        [key] VARCHAR(200),
        Value VARCHAR(MAX),
        type INT
    );

    DECLARE @key VARCHAR(200),
            @Value VARCHAR(MAX),
            @Thetype INT,
            @ii INT,
            @iiMax INT,
            @NewObject INT,
            @firstchar CHAR(1),
            @Path NVARCHAR(MAX); -- Updated to hold the current location path

    INSERT INTO @OpenJSONData
        (
            [key],
            Value,
            type
        )
    SELECT [Key],
           Value,
           Type
    FROM OPENJSON(@JSONData);

    SELECT @ii = 1,
           @iiMax = SCOPE_IDENTITY(),
           @Path = ''; -- Initialize the path as empty

    SELECT @firstchar = --the first character to see if it is an object or an array
        SUBSTRING(@JSONData, PATINDEX('%[^' + CHAR(0) + '- ' + CHAR(160) + ']%', ' ' + @JSONData + '!' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN) - 1, 1);

    IF @type IS NULL AND @firstchar IN ( '[', '{' )
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @ReturnTable
                (
                    SequenceNo,
                    Parent_ID,
                    Object_ID,
                    Name,
                    LocationPath,
                    StringValue,
                    ValueType
                )
            SELECT 1,
                   NULL,
                   1,
                   '-',
                   NULL,
                   '',
                   CASE @firstchar WHEN '[' THEN 'array' ELSE 'object' END;

            SELECT @type = CASE @firstchar WHEN '[' THEN @array ELSE @object END,
                   @Parent_object_ID = 1,
                   @MaxObject_id = COALESCE(@MaxObject_id, 1) + 1;
        END;

    WHILE (@ii <= @iiMax)
        BEGIN
            --OpenJSON renames list items with 0-nn which confuses the consumers of the table
            SELECT @key = CASE WHEN [key] LIKE '[0-9]%' THEN NULL ELSE [key] END,
                   @Value = Value,
                   @Thetype = type
            FROM @OpenJSONData
            WHERE sequence = @ii;

            IF @Thetype IN ( @array, @object ) --if we have been returned an array or object
                BEGIN
                    SELECT @MaxObject_id = COALESCE(@MaxObject_id, 1) + 1;
                    --just in case we have an object or array returned

                    -- Update the path for child elements
                    SET @Path = ISNULL(@Path + '.', '') + @key;

                    -- Record the object itself with the current location path
                    INSERT INTO @ReturnTable
                        (
                            SequenceNo,
                            Parent_ID,
                            Object_ID,
                            Name,
                            LocationPath,
                            StringValue,
                            ValueType
                        )
                    SELECT @ii,
                           @Parent_object_ID,
                           @MaxObject_id,
                           @key,
                           @Path,
                           '',
                           CASE @Thetype WHEN @array THEN 'array' ELSE 'object' END;

                    -- Recursively insert the children of the object with the updated location path
                    INSERT INTO @ReturnTable
                        (
                            SequenceNo,
                            Parent_ID,
                            Object_ID,
                            Name,
                            LocationPath,
                            StringValue,
                            ValueType
                        )
                    SELECT SequenceNo,
                           Parent_ID,
                           Object_ID,
                           Name,
                           @Path + '.' + Name,
                           COALESCE(StringValue, 'null'),
                           ValueType
                    FROM dbo.JSONHierarchy(@Value, @MaxObject_id, @MaxObject_id, @type);

                    SELECT @MaxObject_id = MAX(Object_ID) + 1
                    FROM @ReturnTable;

                    -- Remove the last key from the path for the parent object
                    SET @Path = LEFT(@Path, (LEN(@Path) - LEN(@key) - 1));

                END;
            ELSE
                INSERT INTO @ReturnTable
                    (
                        SequenceNo,
                        Parent_ID,
                        Object_ID,
                        Name,
                        LocationPath, -- Store the full location path for leaf elements
                        StringValue,
                        ValueType
                    )
                SELECT @ii,
                       @Parent_object_ID,
                       NULL,
                       @key,
                       @Path + '.' + @key, -- Concatenate the current key to the path
                       COALESCE(@Value, 'null'),
                       CASE @Thetype
                           WHEN @string THEN 'string'
                           WHEN @null THEN 'null'
                           WHEN @int THEN 'int'
                           WHEN @boolean THEN 'boolean'
                           ELSE 'int'
                       END;

            SELECT @ii = @ii + 1;
        END;

        RETURN;
END;
```

**My Question:**
How can we add these additional fields **KeyPath** and **JSONdata_Used** in the Resultset to retrieve correct data.?

**Note:** The Modified Function Query looks good for obtaining depth of 2 levels.
So, the Actual JSON is as below which is not outputting the correct Result set.

```
DECLARE @JSONData VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @JSONData = 
'[
    { "Id": 1, "Name": "Norma Perry", "Role": "Director of Human Resources",
        "SubOrdinates": [
                            { "Id": 2, "Name": "Bent Grasha", "Role": "Employee Relations Manager",
                                "SubOrdinates": [
                                                    { "Id": 8, "Name": "Birgitta Rosoni", "Role": "Employee Relations Specialist" },
                                                    { "Id": 9, "Name": "Jonis Thring", "Role": "Employee Relations Specialist" },
                                                    { "Id": 10, "Name": "Mickey Neilands", "Role": "Staff Coodinator" }
                                                ]
                            },
                            { "Id": 3, "Name": "Bernadine Godsell", "Role": "Human Resouces Analyst" },
                            { "Id": 4, "Name": "Matteo Gobeaux", "Role": "HR Information Specialist" },
                            { "Id": 5, "Name": "Erica Romaguera", "Role": "Talent Acquisition Manager",
                                "SubOrdinates": [
                                                    { "Id": 11, "Name": "Bernelle Cubley", "Role": "Recruiter" },
                                                    { "Id": 12, "Name": "Debby Lathem", "Role": "Recruiter" },
                                                    { "Id": 13, "Name": "Dorena Whebell", "Role": "Recruiter" },
                                                    { "Id": 14, "Name": "Phil Acres", "Role": "Recruiter" }
                                                ]
                            },
                            { "Id": 6, "Name": "Irwin Spinello", "Role": "Compensation Manager",
                                "SubOrdinates": [
                                                    { "Id": 15, "Name": "Holmes Dever", "Role": "Payroll Administrator",
                                                        "SubOrdinates": [
                                                                            { "Id": 19, "Name": "Bartholemy Durgan", "Role": "Payroll Specialist" },
                                                                            { "Id": 20, "Name": "Berkley Esherwood", "Role": "Payroll Specialist" }
                                                                        ]
                                                    },
                                                    { "Id": 16, "Name": "Brigida Withey", "Role": "Benefits Specialist" },
                                                    { "Id": 17, "Name": "Laney Christmas", "Role": "Benefits Specialist" }
                                                ]
                            },
                            { "Id": 7, "Name": "Percy Veltman", "Role": "Training Manager",
                                "SubOrdinates": [
                                                    { "Id": 18, "Name": "Kendra Scrammage", "Role": "Training Assistant" }
                                                ]
                            }
                        ]
    }
]';
```

**Required Output Resultset for the Main JSONdata:**
[image]

**References:**
For Exact KeyPaths retrieval, i found this CTE useful and simple provided by @renegm:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/284227/100649

Comment: If you made an attempt, include it in the question, not an offsite resource.

Comment: You've already asked this question once. it's usually bad idea to open another one.

Comment: *"I could not add the complete function code as it is too long"* It wasn't, I just added it for you.

Comment: @siggemannen, i had deleted the post due to Flags raised for my 1st edit which doesn't contain the screenshots but it contained plain text and table structures. so with all that info, i deleted that post and created another post which can help reach audience.